# javascript onclick doesnt log in the console

Tags: javascript

```
<button name="button" id="button">convert</button>

var convert_button = document.getElementsByTagName("button"); 

var convert = function () {
    console.log('button is clicked');

};

//set the click handler to the convert

convert_button.onclick = convert;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please describe your question.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns `HTMLCollection` ( wich is an array like object ) .

```
// Supply index
var convert_button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
```

or you can [use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) the `id` of the button like this :

```
var convert_button = document.getElementById("button");
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y0c8w6xe/)

Comment: now it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefinedunit_converter.js:18 (anonymous function)"

Comment: @moy_ted: Note that the `<button>` element must appear in the document **before** `getElement...()` is called. Otherwise, the element will not be found.

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT:

Works on JSFiddle with the code as described by you and adjusted by others.

http://jsfiddle.net/cm09psmf/1/

## End Edit

Use getElementById instead of getElementsByTagName:

```
var convert_button = document.getElementById("button");
```

getElementsByTagName returns array-like objects for which you need to iterate over them but if you have only one in your page, you can do this way:

```
var convert_button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]; //0 for first button
```

Comment: now it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefinedunit_converter.js:18 (anonymous function)"

Comment: It works on JSFiddle, so it must be something else in your code http://jsfiddle.net/cm09psmf/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<button name="button" id="button">convert</button>

//var convert_button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
//this is wrong; returns an
//array not a single object

var convert_button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

var convert = function () {
  console.log('button is clicked');
};

//set the click handler to the convert

convert_button.onclick = convert;
```

Comment: now it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefinedunit_converter.js:18 (anonymous function)"